# Remove blank rows from a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am in search of a formula that can help me remove blank rows from a column. I tried different formulas, but with no luck.

Apreciate the help.

[image]

I can`t use sort because the imput data changes. I tried different formulas found online, but didn`t work.

Comment: If you need a formula then it would be using `INDEX()`+`AGGREGATE()` --> like `=INDEX(A$1:A$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(A$1:A$10)-ROW(A$1)+1)/(A$1:A$10<>""),ROWS(B$1:B1)))` and fill down so this will exclude blanks, but with native feature in excel one can exlcude the blanks, probably some sample data would help. If have access to MS365 then `TOCOL()` or `FILTER()` perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way for those using `Excel 2013`:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$15)/(A$2:A$15<>""),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")
```

---

Or MS365 Users can use `TOCOL()` or `FILTER()`

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(A2:A15,1)
```

---

Or,

```
=FILTER(A2:A15,A2:A15<>"")
```

---

Comment: Thank you. I`m using Excel 2013 and it works great. Really apreciate.